# Epsilon delta definition

Tags: analysis, soft-question

I understand  the definition of  limit. I can use it to prove things, but I still  don't  get the motivation behind it.

Comment: If you can get a copy of Spivak's calculus book, I suggest you take a look at chapter $5$, where he explains the definition of limits. He guides the reader in getting from the intuitive meaning of limits to the rigorous definition of limits in a step-by-step manner.

Comment: "Why isn't there a definition even after 150 years that corresponds better with the intuitive idea of limit?" The standard definition corresponds very well with _my_ intuitive notion of a limit.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who took intro real analysis last quarter, I can relate.

"definition is somehow not capturing the intuitive idea of limit as a variable moving towards a value."

It does, I just think you need to think through the definition more, perhaps see some visuals.
The key is word is $\forall \epsilon > 0$. Imagine starting from a large $\epsilon$ value. You can then find a $\delta$ in the domain for which the definition holds. Now imagine shrinking $\epsilon$ by a little, you can find another $\delta$ which works. Keep shrinking $\epsilon$ until it is super small. You can still find a $\delta$ and a corresponding region for which the definition holds.

This visual might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit . Just imagine shrinking the $\epsilon$.